# how many hours has my laptop display been used?

Tags: display, system-information

I often use my late-2012 AirBook laptop to watch streaming videos through an external monitor using the Thunderbolt port. When I do this, I usually turn the display brightness of my laptops screen all the way down (such that the apple logo on the back in no longer illuminated). I don't know that this counts as the display being "off" but I am curious if (like the battery hours/lifecycle count or other usage info in the System Report) there is a total number of hours tracked for the laptop display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're turning the brightness all the way down, the display is still on, but the backlight for the display is off. I do not believe a backlight tracker exists.

I do not believe a display tracker exists either.

However, assuming you rarely or never use your MBP with the screen closed (needs external keyboard/mouse/screen), you can calculate a rough estimate by multiplying the battery's cycle count by the average lifespan of the battery (100%-0%). I'm not sure why this information would be relevant, but for example if I have a cycle count of 460 and my battery generally lasts for about 7 hours, I'd have a display count of (very roughly) about 3200 hours.